# Duplicate records sybase query

Tags: duplicates, sybase

Could anyone help me in below scenario to generate query in Sybase.

Records:

refid  |  name | deptname | joinDate

1     |  bob  | admin    | 05-25-1998

1     |  bob  | admin    | null

2    |   rosy | admin   |  01-29-2001

3     |  john  | finance |  null

4    |   sam  | finance  | 01-29-2005

Here, I want to remove 2nd row as first 3 columns values are same and in 2nd row has null value. So i want to consider only first row.

Anyone create a sample query of it.

Thanks,
Samrat

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t1 (refid int, name varchar(30), deptname name varchar(30), joinDate datetime)
create unique index ix1 on t1(refid, name, deptname) with ignore_dup_key
go
```

...now insert your rows...

When a duplicate key occurs, the inserted row is discarded but the transaction continues. The order in which the rows are inserted, therefore matters.